# Sampling weights for subpopulations in R

Tags: r, sampling, r-lavaan

I'm working with a large, national survey that was collected using complex survey methods.  As such, I'm needing to account for sample weights and other survey design features (e.g., sampling strata).  I'm new to this methodology, so apologies if the answers here are obvious.

I've had success running path analysis models using the 'lavaan' package paired with the 'lavaan.survey' package.  However, some of my models involve only a subset of the data (e.g., only female participants).

How can I adjust the sample weights to reflect the fact that I am only analyzing a subsample (e.g., females)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subset()` function in the survey package handles subpopulations correctly, and since `lavaan.survey` uses the survey package to get the basic standard errors for the population covariance matrix, it should all flow through properly.